# Sequel Gem TZInfo to UTC offset - City Name in the front end

Tags: ruby, sequel, tzinfo

I have a model defined in my backend which is defined as

```
class TimezoneIdentifier < Sequel::Model
end
```

In my front end react component, I need to display the timezones in the format UTC-5 Ontario and so on. Is there a way of doing this?

My database has all the timezone identifiers from the TZInfo gem.

I am not using Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement functionality similar to `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`'s. Check out `#to_s`, `#formatted_offset`, `#utc_offset` here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb#L306

Or you can use `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` without the rest of `ActiveSupport` with `require 'active_support/values/time_zone'`.